# Making Ubuntu Server 20.04 smaller or using other distribution

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I've used Ubuntu Server in the past (a time long, long ago) because of it's LTS and hardware support.
Currently I'm in a similar situation where I need to install both physical and virtual machines that  must get security updates for as long as possible. Very little functionality will be needed (ssh, bind9, dhcp-server, samba).
I installed Ubuntu Server 20.04.2 in a VM for test. It uses more than 4GB of disk space after installation which feels far too much for the actual functionality needed. (Doc states 2.5 minimal disk space?)

Is there a way to safely remove unneeded packages to get a more minimalistic system?
Or should I use another distribution and which one? LTS is important.

I would like to keep disk and memory footprints as low as possible because the systems have to run on older hardware.

Answer (score 1):

Debian requires less (I have an actual machine where it takes less than a GiB raw on disk, including any filesystem metadata and so on). And it's what Ubuntu is based upon. Having said that, I don't see any reason to use Ubuntu Server at all. For a desktop, maybe; for a server, I can't just understand why people use Ubuntu Server instead of Debian.

Comment: People use Ubuntu for the hardware support. Debian require some additional steps.

Answer (score 0):

When you installed Ubuntu Server, did you de-select all of the software selections? It may be possible to slim the server install down by initially removing everything possible, then installing only what's needed. Check the drive usage at each step as well, as from memory samba needs a fair chunk of drive space.

Using the minimal-installer ISO *might* save more space, but I'm pretty sure it's the same package lists as the server ISO.